# Show that for any $k$-cycle $(a_1 a_2...a_k) \in S_n$, and for any permutation $\pi \in S_n$, $\pi(a_1...a_k)\pi^{-1}=(\pi(a_1)..\pi(a_k))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Show that for any $k$-cycle $(a_1 a_2...a_k) \in S_n$ where $S_n$ is the set of all permutations of n elements and $(a_1...a_k)$ represents a cycle, like $a_1$ goes to $a_2$ and ... and $a_k$ goes to $a_1$, and for any permutation $\pi \in S_n$, $\pi(a_1...a_k)\pi^{-1}=(\pi(a_1)..\pi(a_k))$.

I thought about this logically, like if an element is not moved in the cycle, then the permutation $\pi$ and $\pi^{-1}$ will just move it back to its original location.  But I'm not really sure why the final elements from these permutations are in the form $\pi(a_i)$ instead of having a $\pi^{-1}$ in it somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, why is: $\pi(a_1...a_k)\pi^{-1}=(\pi(a_1)..\pi(a_k))$, notice what happens if you apply the left side, or the right side, to the number $\pi(a_n)$. In both cases, the result is $\pi(a_{n+1})$   (where $a_{k+1}$ denotes $a_1$).

Answer (score 0):

For all $n= 1,2,\;...\;,k$, we have
$$\pi(i_1\;i_2\;...\;i_k)\pi^{-1}(\pi(i_n))=\pi(i_1\;i_2\;...\;i_k)(i_n)=\pi(i_{n+1})$$
$$(\pi(i_1)\;\pi(i_2)\;...\;\pi(i_k))(\pi(i_n))=\pi(i_{n+1})$$

The LHS and RHS of the proposition can clearly be seen to be the same now. Since the permutation $\pi$ is a bijective map, the proposition is hence proven.